# Good REST API design for operations on resource sets

Tags: rest, api, post, put, http-delete

With REST it is pretty clear how to operate on resources, e.g.

```
PUT /users/{userId} - updates the user with userId
GET /users/{userId} - reads the user with userId
```

Similarly for resource sets

```
POST /users - creates a new user
GET /users/{userId}/books - reads list of books from a user
GET /users/{userId}/books?filter=x - reads list of books from a user with specific filter
```

What if I want to develop more elaborate operations on **resource sets**, e.g.

1. with the request body, add a list of books to the existing list and accepting duplicates (basically concatenating the list)

```
POST /users/{userId}/books 
or PUT /users/{userId}/books 
or PATCH?
or POST /users/{userId}/books/concatenate
```

2. with the request body, add a list of books to the existing list but no duplicates (basically merging the list)

```
POST /users/{userId}/books 
or PUT /users/{userId}/books 
or PATCH?
or POST /users/{userId}/books/merge
```

3. also for deleting parts of resource sets:
   with the request body, delete a list of books from the existing list that have a certain property

```
POST /users/{userId}/books/delete?category=x 
or DELETE /users/{userId}/books?category=x
```

4. or deleting all resources in a resource set:

```
POST /users/{userId}/books/delete_all 
or DELETE /users/{userId}/books
```

Would be thankful for some hints or guidelines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Resource sets", from the point of view of REST, are a fiction.  There are only resources.  As far as a general-purpose HTTP component is concerned, there is _no relation implied by the following URI:

```
/users
/users/{userId}
/users/{userId}/books
/users/{userId}/books?filter=x
/users/{userId}/books/concatenate
```

They are completely independent of one another; for instance, `DELETE /users` does not imply *anything* about the other resources.

We *human beings* tend to assign identifiers in patterns that make sense, but the machines don't care.

> with the request body, add a list of books to the existing list and accepting duplicates (basically concatenating the list)

PUT and PATCH have remote authoring semantics; they act like you would expect if you were trying to edit a copy of a file on the server.  You `GET` a copy of the current representation of the resource, make edits to your local copy, and then request that the server change its copy to match your copy.  With `PUT`, you send a complete copy of your representation of the resource; with PATCH, you send a patch-document that describes the changes you made.

[It's okay to use POST](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post); HTML got along just fine using nothing but GET and POST, and the web took over the world.

You don't need a separate resource for POST; you can use one if you like, but it isn't necessary to do so.

> with the request body, add a list of books to the existing list but no duplicates (basically merging the list)

Not really any different; what we agree upon in HTTP is the *semantics* of the request and response messages.  What the server chooses to do is an implementation concern.  See [Fielding 2002](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-tag/2002Apr/0207.html).

So if I send to you a representation of a list with duplicate entries, and you strip out the duplicates, that's "fine"; you just need to exercise some care with your responses to ensure that you don't imply that you accepted the requested representation as is.

With PATCH, it's a bit fuzzy, in that the RFC describes [all or nothing](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789#section-2) semantics, but based on the language used it is reasonable to infer that the implementation is restricted as well.

> also for deleting parts of resource sets: with the request body, delete a list of books from the existing list that have a certain property

Give RFC 7231 a careful read: [DELETE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.5) doesn't quite mean what your examples hint at.  DELETE breaks the associate between a key (the target uri) and a value (the resource representations), but that doesn't necessarily mean "and also garbage collect the representation".

The same idea expressed another way -- suppose I `GET /list-of-books` from the server, and the returned representation is a list of three books.  In the case where I want that resource to instead return a representation of an *empty* list, `DELETE` is the wrong tool.  `DELETE` tells the server that I want future calls to `GET /list-of-books` to return `404 Not Found` or possibly `410 Gone`.  If what I really want is a `200 OK` with an empty list, then I need to PUT/PATCH/POST/etc. the resource.

> deleting all resources in a resource set

Same problem as before.

> With REST it is pretty clear how to operate on resources

This is the problem - it is NOT clear how to operate on resources.  The web is cluttered with literature that makes a complete hash of it (we use REST to fetch documents that mangle the lessons of REST -- fabulous irony).

REST includes a uniform interface as a constraint.  In HTTP, that interface is effectively a document store.  PUT and PATCH just edit document contents - which is perfectly satisfactory if your domain is anemic or declarative.  For anything else where we don't have standardized semantics, we use POST.

See Jim Webber, 2011:  "You have to learn how to use HTTP to trigger business activity as a side effect of moving documents around the network."